# How i can pass array (argument ) to javascript function in .js file?

Tags: javascript

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)

    public String home(Locale locale, Model model)
    {
          float[] tab=new float[1000];
          for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
           {
                tab[i]=i;
           }
      model.addAttribute("tab_index",tab);
      return "index";
    }   

// *********************** index .jsp ******************    
<html>   
<body>   
  <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/file1.js">                            
  </script>    
                 <script type="text/javascript" >                 
                     fct(${tab_index});     
                 </script>     
</body>     
</html>     
// *********************  file1.js **************************
function fct(a)    
{    
    alert("table : "+a[0]);    
}
```

/*   if a pass a simple type (float , int ... ) all work right ... but if a pass an array argument it can call the javascript function */

Comment: You pass arrays like you pass ints/floats/strings/etc. What's the exact problem you run into when passing arrays?

Comment: the problem that i dont see the " alert " so it did not call the function "fct" only when i pass an array argument

Comment: What language is this? Add a language tag.

Comment: torazaburo the language is jsp (library JSTL)